# Open an UIView when click a Link on UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview

How can I open an UIView when click a Link on UIWebview?

I've a project iOS UIWeview, and I need open an UIView when click some link.

I tried use this on my ViewController UIWebview:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@" In - shouldStartLoadWithRequest ");

    return YES; }
```

I did something wrong?

Thanks!

**Solution:**

*on: myViewController.h*

```
ViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Comment: What isn't working? If you just don't want to load the page, just return `NO`instead of `YES`.

Comment: it's never called, never printed my log..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the delegate for the webview?